# How to ensure only one derby database is created and used by my Jar file?

Tags: java, derby

I have created a JAR file with my java program that uses an embedded derby database. Then I converted that JAR file to a .exe file. Everything works fine except that when I copy the icon to the desktop, all of the database files are saved there when I launch the program. To combat this, I launch it in a separate folder and once the database files are made in that folder I copy a shortcut to the executable onto my desktop. Even after I do this though, the application will not read from the existing database files and it will create new database files on my desktop. How do I make it so that it will read from the files in one location and not recreate it everytime I open it in a new place?

Comment: Change the working directory (starts in) of the short so it points where you want the files created.  A better solution is to provide a well known location for the files to be stored in (like `~/AppData/...`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think you are right. Right now my code is creating the database in the current working directory. Is that what I should change to a "well-known location"

Comment: [Derby JDBC database connection URL](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html), [Embedded Derby JDBC database connection URL](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/devguide/rdevdvlp38881.html)